# -fps filter not in avconv?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, frame-rate, libx264, avconv

Used a older version of ffmpeg on a project and now im planning on switching over to avconv and was wondering if the -fps filter has been changed or depreciated? If it has been changed what is the current substitute for the -fps filter in avconv? Much Thanks

Comment: Why would you switch to `avconv` when a recent `ffmpeg` would do? Filter support is much better in `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `-r` works quite well. But you care correct it does seem that fps filter has seen better days. It does almost work sometimes, but not others.

Make sure to use -r right before the output file, otherwise it can be interpreted to be the frame rate of one of the input streams if you write your command in some ways.